# .htaccess Page not found after adding exception

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file which i want to use to rewrite all to index.php apart from configurator.php.
This is working fine for me with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/configurator [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

With that i can write stuff like "localhost/mypage/about-us" and this is send to the index page.
Now i want to write something like "localhost/mypage/configurator/test". But if i do so i get a "page not found" error with that code:

```
<Files "/configurator.php">
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ configurator.php?page=$1 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</Files>
```

The only thing that works with the configurator is writing either "localhost/mypage/configurator" or "localhost/mypage/configurator?page=test.

Why isnt it working as intendet?

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# handle configurator 
RewriteRule ^(configurator)/(.+) $1.php?url=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mypage/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# front controller rule
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: but how do i grab the variable after the configurator? like "configurator/test" how do i access the "test" with php? (and now my anchors (a href='test') redirect me to "localhost/mypage/test" instead of "localhost/mypage/configurator/test")

Comment: REQUEST_URI has it after first slash. We can pass over GET variable also if that suits better

Comment: With GET i cant access it, its easier for me, cause i am pretty new to php and htaccess :D

Comment: With that it doesnt see the configurator file, it just prints it as it was inside my index page ._.

Comment: Do you have a .htccess inside `configurator/` directory? If not place your full .htaccess in question and also tell which URL you are using for testing?

Comment: configurator is a php file in my main directory. same as .htaccess and index.php (sorry i should have given this maybe a bit before)

Comment: ok just copy/paste my updated .htaccess as is and test with `localhost/mypage/configurator/test123`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233039/discussion-between-jonas-adam-and-anubhava).